# Dos libpcap free memory ifself?

Tags: libpcap, winpcap

My program use libpcap like this:

> while pcaket = pcap_next() {
>
> ```
> ...
>
> (modify the pcaket and do checksum)
>
> ...
>
> pcap_sendpacket(pcaket)
> ```
>
> }

Recently, I found there is a memory leak in my program...

My question is: 
**Will the libpcap free the pcaket after pcap_next? or I have to do the free work myself ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Will the libpcap free the pcaket after pcap_next?

The packet is contained in a buffer internal to libpcap (attached to the `pcap_t`); a new buffer is not allocated for each packet, so the buffer isn't freed after `pcap_next()`, it's freed after the `pcap_t` is closed.  You do not have to free it yourself.

(This also means that the packet data from a particular call to `pcap_next()` or `pcap_next_ex()` is *not* guaranteed to remain valid after the next call to `pcap_next()` or `pcap_next_ex()` - or `pcap_loop()` or `pcap_dispatch()`; it might be overwritten with data from the next packet or the next batch of packets.)

Comment: Thanks, but what if my program can not process so many packets in time, will the libpcap hold more and more packet and cost out of memory?

Comment: No, the pcap buffer is of a fixed size, and if your program cannot process the packets as they arrive, and so a packet arrives when the buffer is full, the packet is not put in the buffer, so your program will not see it.  You can use `pcap_stats()` on some platforms to get a count of the packets that couldn't be put into the pcap buffer.